# Bezout's Theorem for less than n polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The Wikipedia formulation of Bezout's theorem states that the number of intersection points with multiplicity of n homogeneous polynomials in n + 1 indeterminates with no common components is the product of the degrees of the polynomials in the complex projective space.

What does this theorem imply for n - 1 polynomials in n + 1 indeterminates? I am particularly interested in the intersection of a deg 1 and a deg 2 homogenous polynomials in four variables.

Any answers or references would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $n-1$ (general) homogeneous polynomials in $n+1$ variables will not intersect to give some points but rather to give a projective curve. There is a lot you can say about this curve (it's a [complete intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection) in projective space) for example you can compute its genus (see the [adjunction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula)) given the degrees of the polynomials but curves have complicated internal structure and therefore don't have a straightforward description like ''there are exactly N points''.